# How to extend model to get data from third party extension?

Tags: magento2, grid

I have a third party extension here and it has its own grid, and what I want to do is I'm going to create a custom module to make a grid in the backend using the data from that third party extension grid. Is this possible? And I'd like to know how or what should I do next? thank you.